# What is wrong with File.Exists?

Tags: c#, file

I am sitting here since 2 hours to find a solution for my problem. I wanna check whether a file exist.

I have a `ButtonCreate` class and in this class I create a Directory `newSFO`, the name of the Directory being *MUMO*. Then I want to check whether the file `newSFoZipName` exist and if the file exists do not create it. But it is not working. Thanks in advance!

```
newSFoZipName = MySubFName + MytbRevision + "__C8" + MyLastCh + ".zip";

if (LastCh == "M")
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"M");
    tbRFolder = rgx.Replace(LastCh, "Mumo");
    newSFo = Path.Combine(newSubPath, tbRFolder);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newSFo);
    newSFoZip = Path.Combine(newSFo, newSFoZipName);
   // File.Create(newSFoZipName).Close();

    //string path2 = newSFo + newSFoZip;
    File.Create(newSFoZipName).Close();

    if (Directory.Exists(newSFoZip))
    {
        if (!File.Exists(newSFoZipName))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File exists");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "But it is not working" is not an adequate description of the problem. Please explain what happens, compared with what you expected to happen.

Comment: About the Regex, why don't you just use a `string.Replace`?

Comment: I have a ComboBox List Objekts
List Objekts:

bla bla M
bub bub L

And i use to Regex to Replace LastCharacter M of the List Box with Mumo to create a Directory Path with this. And in this Directory Path i wann create a zip File..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You write

```
if (!File.Exists(newSFoZipName))
{
    MessageBox.Show("File exists");
}
```

instead of

```
if (File.Exists(newSFoZipName))
{
    MessageBox.Show("File exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can also write this

```
 if (!File.Exists(newSFoZipName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File Not Exists"); //code to create file here
    }
else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File Exists");
    }
```

Comment: if (!File.Exists(newSFoZipName))
    {
File.Create(newSFoZipName); } is it creating or any error message